# What is で doing in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, nuances, particle-で

A guy is buying Oden at the conbini and the clerk asks:

> おつゆこれぐらいで?

So the guy answers:

> うん、そんなもんでいいです

I think it means something like: is this much soup ok? But I don't really know why で is used at the end of the first sentence  or in the middle of the second.
I also don't get the meaning of the second sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that で is being used the same way in both sentences.

Essentially it kind of makes what comes before it -- "これぐらい" and "そんなもん" -- into a "state" or "condition" or "situation" to be referred to.

But in the first case the sentence is truncated, which is a normal thing in everyday use. More politely, the conbini person should probably say "これぐらいでよろしいですか"

"これぐらい + で" = the state of being about this much
"よろしいですか" = is it good/acceptable/satisfactory?

"そんなもん" is "that kind of state" or "that sort of situation" or "that kind of thing" or, in this case specifically "that amount". So the second sentence is "Yeah, that's about right" or "Yeah, that's good"

"そんなもん + で" = that kind of situation/condition (that amount)
"いいです" = is good/acceptable/satisfactory

This is a super common and ordinary use of "で" and I'm sure that such examples abound in normal conversation.

For example if you just order "まぐろ" at the sushi joint, they may ask "さしみで？" = "as sashimi" or "in the state of sashimi". But if you wanted nigiri sushi you could say "にぎりでお願いします" = "as nigiri please"

Or sake... "あつかんで？" = "as warm sake", but if you want chilled sake, you would say "ひやで" or, more politely, "ひやでお願いします"